# Including the og:video tag on a product detail page

Tags: video, facebook-opengraph

We are trying to use the og:video tag and related markup to enable in-NewsFeed video playing for product detail pages from our website that are shared via Facebook.

For example, we have implemented the tags here:

http://www.ice.com/product/bracelets/womens-silver-bracelet-prd_bsw_106235

and are using:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Refined and glamorous, this bangle bracelet is studded with sparkling yellow crystals. Crafted from stainless steel, this lovely piece offers a classic and elegant look for any occasion. Wear it alone or stack a few together for a unique look. - BSW_106235" />
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="144519415627" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ice.com/product/bracelets/womens-silver-bracelet-prd_bsw_106235" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.ice.com/ice/product/images/BSW/BSW_106235_b_l-Stainless_Steel_and_L_Topaz_Bangle.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Yellow Crystal Stainless Steel Bangle - BSW_106235" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://videos.treepodia.com/UA-ICE/BSW106235.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="360" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="280" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

When I share the link for this product detail page in Facebook, the video thumbnail and option to play the video within the newsfeed are not available.

Are we doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, I just tried it in my facebook account and it worked - preview image showed up and the video played.

You can check it with your URL [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.ice.com/product/bracelets/womens-silver-bracelet-prd_bsw_106235).

Just make sure you're using facebook via https, otherwise no external content will play.